# ember.js have view's function observes controller's property

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-view

I have written a view:

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
  select: null,
  modify: null,

  createSelect: function() {
    return new ol.interaction.Select();
  },

  onMapCreated: function() {
    this.select = this.createSelect();
    this.modify = this.createModify();
  },

  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.get('controller').addObserver('olMap', this.onMapCreated);
  },
});
```

The view is added in a template related to a controller which has an **olMap** property.
I need to wait for the **olMap** property to be instantiated before doing some work in my view.

The code above is kind of working, except that the **this** referenced in the **onMapCreated** function is the controller's instance and not the view's instance.

I'm quite sure I am doing something wrong in my application's design. I would like to separate the concerns and get the *drawing* part outside of the main controller. Should I use a component? Not sure because it's not going to be reusable...

I would love to have some directions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've ended up with:

My setup:

> Ember      : 1.10.0
>
> Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.16
>
> jQuery     : 1.11.2

Directory structure:

- controllers:

  - map.js
  - map-draw.js
- templates

  - map.hbs
  - map-draw.hbs
- views

  - map.js
  - map-draw.js

in the template **templates/map.js** I use a render helper like this:

```
{{render "mapDraw" mapDraw}}
```

the renderer uses the controller **controllers/map-draw.js** and the view **views/map-draw.js**

content of the view **map-draw.js**:

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: "mapDraw",
  classNames: ["map-draw"]
});
```

in the controller **map-draw.js** I am binding the **map.js** controller.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({    
  needs: ['map'],
  olMap: null,
  //...//
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.get('controllers.map').addObserver('olMap', this, function(sender) {
      this.set('olMap', sender.get('olMap'));
    });
  }
  //...//
});
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading the manual in the API section, I came up with the solution. I post it here is someone needs it someday. Actually, all I had to do is add a parameter **this** to the **addObserver** method in order to change the context.

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
  select: null,
  modify: null,

  createSelect: function() {
    return new ol.interaction.Select();
  },

  onMapCreated: function() {
    this.select = this.createSelect();
    this.modify = this.createModify();
  },

  init: function() {
    this._super();
    this.get('controller').addObserver('olMap', this, this.onMapCreated);
  },
});
```

Comment: I found something cleaner, I'll post an answer with that later on